# how can we create secure php code using ioncube in php?

Tags: passwords

I want to create security for my php code in product. I heared the ioncube is used to secure our code by encode the line. How to create encoded line in ioncube and view the output in php?

Comment: Could you help me hack stuff?

Answer (score 1):

No, [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is not reversible. It can only be cracked through [brute-force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) or [dictionary-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack) cryptographic attacks. There are tools that can be used to perform such attacks for known password hashes, but unless you have some *serious* computer resources at your disposal you would have to wait for a **very long** time.

Comment: Which is of course the whole reason that the hashes were saved instead of the passwords themselves in the first place: to prevent anyone doing what the OP is trying!

Comment: @DSM: Exactly. An MD5 password would still be a relatively hard nut to crack for anyone without at-least a mid-size computer cluster, unless of course the password was something along the lines of "1234"...

Answer (score 0):

Test every possbile password individually for each user. Eventually you will find a match for all of them.

You will need to spend hundreds of thousands of dollars on hardware and millions of dollars on your electricity bill, and it will take a very long time.

Wordpress deliberately tried to make this very difficult to do.